# rvm cookbook fails installing ruby within vagrant

Tags: rvm, chef-infra, vagrant

I've been running into issues when trying to run the `rvm::user` recipe from [fnichol/chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm). I'm using chef along with a Vagrant box. rvm installs fine, but every time chef tries to install a ruby, it fails with this error:

```
WARN: Failed to install rvm_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p448]. Check logs in /log/ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Here's my `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box       = 'precise32'
  config.vm.box_url   = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box'

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "rvm::vagrant" 
    chef.add_recipe "rvm::user"

    chef.json = {
      :rvm => {
        :user_installs => [
           {
              :user => "vagrant",
              :default_ruby => "1.9.3",
              :rubies => ["1.9.3"],
              :global_gems => [
                  { :name => 'bundler' }
              ],                   
           }
        ]
      }
  end
end
```

- Environment Details:

  - Vagrant version: `1.2.7`
  - Vagrant vm: `precise32`
  - rvm version: `1.22.11`
  - chef-rvm ref: `59dc482`

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that Vagrant was running chef in a non-interactive/non-tty session. The `sudo` command doesn't like to run in non-interactive sessions, and causes rvm to fail when it tries install dependencies (via apt-get in ubuntu).

You can allow sudo to run non-interactively by adding this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
vagrant  ALL= (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Once I added this, chef installed the `rvm::user` recipe successfully.

Comment: I thought this was default setup for vagrant boxes

Answer (score 0):

My setup was much more complicated, however the error was the same. Ultimately i found that adding the apt chef recipe fixed everything.

```
chef.add_recipe "apt" 
chef.add_recipe "rvm::vagrant" 
chef.add_recipe "rvm::user"

> Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[curl], recipe[rvm::vagrant], recipe[rvm::user]]
```

Adding the line

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

didn't work for my scenario.

I believe the apt chef recipe runs apt update which fixes an issue with old and ill matched  versions.

The error messages i received were

```
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[libxml2-dev]'
apt-get -q -y install libxml2-dev=2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.1 returned 100, expected 0
....
Error executing action `install` on resource 'rvm_ruby[2.1.1]'
```